# Kerio Control IPSec clients can't access local network

Tags: vpn, kerio

I'm struggled with configuring Kerio Control IPsec VPN server: everything done by the book, using pre shared key. I have local network 192.168.10.0/24 and VPN network is 10.253.98.0/24 I have firewall rules that VPN clients can access local/trusted interface. But when client connects, he gets IP address 10.253.98.3 and can't ping and access 192.168.10.0/24 network. Am I missing something? Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a routing table that links that traffic to your local network. If the client is getting the IP address of your VPN it means that there's routing missing there, the VPN doesn't know where should the traffic be sent to, so it stops at the VPN.